# Cannot change icon on folder on desktop of 20.04

Tags: nautilus, icons, mega

I am fairly incompetent with Ubuntu and old so please forgive me if I ask something stupid.

My problem is that I can't change the icon on a folder on my desktop on 20.04. I have tried the usual method. 
Rt click folder. Properties. Click on displayed icon. Select new icon.

This PARTIALLY works. It works in 'files'. If I go to files and look at desktop then sure enough it has the new icon. But.... on the desktop itself it does not change. It remains as the original standard icon for a folder.

I do not have any folder changing software installed.

My only question would be that I installed 'mega' files integration with nautilus. I can't see how this works and how to remove it. Could that cause any problems?

I should add that it is the mega files 'sync' folder that I am trying to change the icon on.

The folder works perfectly. It's just that I want it to have the mega logo on it so that I can easily spot it on my desktop.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a bug. GNOME developers removed the SW code related to some desktop operations. EDIT: <del>If you notice, for example you cannot do copy/paste operations directly on the desktop, you can do them only if you operate directly inside the Desktop folder. Similarly, you can create new files/folders only if you are inside the desktop folder, but not with a right click of the mouse in yur desktop.</del> For example, drag and drop from a folder to desktop is not possible.

I've recreated your scenario in my Ubuntu 20.04 installation and what happens is the same as in your installation: I can change the icon from inside the Desktop folder, but I cannot see the new icon from the Desktop.

I don't know if it really exists a way to solve it, due to the fact that GNOME lacks of code to perfomr operations directly from the desktop (by a voluntary programmers decision)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Though, as an experiment I just copied and pasted a folder on my desktop and it worked perfectly.

Comment: You are right: it's the drag and drop feature that is not enabled, copy/paste is possible. I wrote something that is not exact, I will partially modify my previous answer.

Comment: Yes you are right. But I still don't see why we can't change desktop icons. Shame it would be really useful.

Comment: A related issue is that it would be very useful to change the basic desktop folder icon to something more 'readable'. I find the colour and lack of strong outline difficult. Also the text is difficult to read. I have a pale blue desktop background colour. Perhaps if the developers could just have a look at offering a different icon set for the desktop that would be helpful. Please. Unless I am missing something and it is possible but I can't find out how. Thanks

Comment: Solved. Kind of. I installed LXQt desktop. It turns out to be the kind of desktop that I like. And I installed a set of icons and changed the icon to what I wanted. Plus I find the destop combination with font more readable. Thanks for your help. All the best.

Comment: Currently, the only solution (until GNOME will restore all desktop features, I don't know if there's a schedule for this) is to change DE so that you can use its desktop features.

Comment: Thanks Lorenz. The most interesting aspect of this is that a whole desktop just sitting there empty seems such a waste to  me  and reduces my productivity. Is this seen as a positive design feature? Perhaps it's just the way I work but I like the things I use all the time to be on the desktop. Anyway... apart from that I love Ubuntu 20.04 and thanks to all of the developers.

Answer (score 0):

The default extension for GNOME is now outdated, so I recommend you to try another one that adds configurations for icons in desktop, like what you are asking. One example is [Desktop Icons: Neo](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4337/desktop-icons-neo/).

This extension lets you change folder images in the way you are trying (properties in <kbd>right-click</kbd>).

Lastly, disable the older *Desktop icons* extension from GNOME Tweaks or from the [official GNOME extensions website](https://extensions.gnome.org/). If you have compatibility issues, try disabling it from the native Extensions app (the one that comes with Ubuntu).